# How to Get Cell value from Excel sheet in Java according to particular Column name and Row name

Tags: java, apache

I want to get cell value according to the particular column name and row name. 
This is the code that I have written to achieve it. It's working fine for the first sheet in the workbook but giving me Null pointer exception for the other sheet in the same workbook.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader {

   public FileInputStream fis; 
   String path = null;
   private XSSFWorkbook workbook=null;
   private XSSFSheet sheet;
   private XSSFRow row=null;
   private XSSFCell cell=null;


    public ExcelReader() throws IOException {

    path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Testdata.xlsx";
    fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    }

    public String getCellData(String sheetName, String testDataType, String testDataID) throws IOException {
        sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<=sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(0);
            cell = row.getCell(i);

            if(cell.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase(testDataType)) {
                break;
                }
        }



        for(int j=0; j<=sheet.getLastRowNum();j++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(j);
            cell= row.getCell(0);
             DataFormatter df2 = new DataFormatter();
             String valueAsString = df2.formatCellValue(cell);
            if(testDataID.equals(valueAsString)) {
                break;
            }

        }

        cell=row.getCell(i);
        String S= cell.getStringCellValue();
        fis.close();
        return S;

    }

}
```

Comment: while line causes the NPE?

Comment: If you are asking which line throws NPE, then it's this line in the code // if(cell.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase(testDataType))//

Comment: so either `cell` or `cell.getStringCellValue()` is null. I could tell you how to fix it, but what is your Code supposed to do? What's the meaning of this for loop anyway? The next for loop overrides your `cell` member anyway. :-O

Comment: Hi Alexander. I'am trying to get the cell data from the specific row and column. The rows have unique IDs (testDataID) and Column has unique names (testDataType). That's why on first loop I'm iterating through all the cells of row 0 to get the name (testDataType) and if condition to confirm and then break out of the loop. The Variable "i" then will have the value of Column number or cell number. On the next loop, I'm doing the same with rows, iterating through the rows by keeping cell index '0', this should iterate through the first cell of every row which is "testDataID".